# Slow query when using datediff function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, datediff

As my title, I have the following code:

```
 SELECT
        *
    FROM
        de.Department
    WHERE
        de.flag = 1
        AND   de.DepartmentNum IN (10,4)
        AND   de.status IN (0,-1,100)
        AND   datediff('dd',de.datequit,'30-SEP-19') > 9
```

The datediff function make my query run very slow(16s for 11 records), and cost also very high(~43k).

Here is my datediff function code

```
create or replace FUNCTION       DATEDIFF 
(
  P_TYPE_DATE IN VARCHAR2 
, P_START_DATE IN TIMESTAMP 
, P_END_DATE IN TIMESTAMP 
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
  v_Result NUMBER := -1;
BEGIN

  IF P_TYPE_DATE IS NOT NULL AND P_START_DATE IS NOT NULL AND P_END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN
    CASE UPPER(P_TYPE_DATE) 
        WHEN 'DD' THEN RETURN ROUND(TRUNC(P_END_DATE,'DD') - TRUNC(P_START_DATE,'DD'),0);
        WHEN 'HH' THEN RETURN ROUND((TRUNC(P_END_DATE,'HH') - TRUNC(P_START_DATE,'HH')) * 24,0);
        WHEN 'MI' THEN RETURN ROUND((TRUNC(P_END_DATE,'MI') - TRUNC(P_START_DATE,'MI')) * 24 * 60,0);
        WHEN 'SS' THEN RETURN ROUND((TRUNC(P_END_DATE,'MI') - TRUNC(P_START_DATE,'MI')) * 24 * 60 * 60 + extract(second from (P_END_DATE - P_START_DATE)),0);
        ELSE RETURN NULL;
    END CASE;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END DATEDIFF;
```

I used SELECT * because I want to get almost column in Department table, so it no more change if I SELECT some columns which I need.

Can I re-write to improve performance and cost?

Mayny thanks!

Comment: Im assuming you have tagged this incorrectly and are actually using SQL Server. Its a known issue. Some alternatives are listed on this page. http://sqltouch.blogspot.com/2013/11/datediff-function-common-performance.html

Comment: Oracle has no `datediff()` your query will not run at all - and simply fail with an error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I created a function named datediff as a datediff function in SQL, sir

Comment: @thewindlove123 Then your question should be "Why is my DATEDIFF function so slow" and post the DATEDIFF function code

Comment: @CathalMF I added code, thanks for advice

Comment: Why do you create such a function if Oracle already supports that with a much simpler syntax?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm a newbie at Oracle, I familiar with SQL server, So i tried to create anything without thinking about result. And now I must tuning one by one stored procedures, packages,....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I created a function named datediff as a datediff function in SQL, sir

Don't use custom functions as they prevent Oracle from using an index on the column; instead just compare the column to the static values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Department
WHERE  flag = 1
AND    DepartmentNum IN (10,4)
AND    status IN (0,-1,100)
AND    datequit > DATE '2019-09-30' + INTERVAL '9' DAY
```

or

```sql
AND    datequit > DATE '2019-09-30' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 9, 'DAY' )
```

or

```sql
AND    datequit > DATE '2019-09-30' + 9
```

> Here is my datediff function code
>
> ```sql
> ...
> WHEN 'DD' THEN RETURN ROUND(TRUNC(P_END_DATE,'DD') - TRUNC(P_START_DATE,'DD'),0);
> ...
> ```

If you want to do an equivalent comparison to using `TRUNC` to ignore the time components then change from using greater-than comparison to using greater-than-or-equal-to and add one time unit (day in your example) to the expected difference. For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Department
WHERE  flag = 1
AND    DepartmentNum IN (10,4)
AND    status IN (0,-1,100)
AND    datequit >= DATE '2019-09-30' + INTERVAL '10' DAY
```

Comment: 3 cases return "no rows selected" (more than 8k5 rows if I use datediff)

Comment: @thewindlove123 I do not have sufficient context to understand what that comment means. Is fewer "no rows selected" a good thing or a bad thing? If it is an issue then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58165013/edit) your question include test data that demonstrates the issue and your expected output for that test data.

Comment: Why is greater-than-or-equal-to while my statement is '30-SEP-19' - datequit > 9 ?
It correct If I choose less-than-or-equal-to, not greater-than sir. 

However, cost include from 43k to more than 100k

Comment: If you are not `TRUNC`ating the time stamp then you will have fractional days in the difference so you need to change from `integer_difference > 9` to `decimal_difference >= 10`. If you leave it as `decimal_difference > 9` then it will also match differences of 9.00001 through 9.99999 days which is not what was included in your previous result.

Comment: @thewindlove123 Cost is not always the best metric as Oracle will not determine the total cost of a user-defined function. [[1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/ext_optimizer.htm#sthref428)]  states "The cost of evaluating a user-defined function depends on the algorithm and the statistical properties of its arguments. It is not practical to store statistics for all possible combinations of columns that could be used as arguments for all functions." If you want accurate UDF costs then you need to look at the extensible optimizer features and generate your own statistics